# Add category to all post by using sql query?

Tags: posts, categories

I have a thousand posts and all them don't have category.

Do you know how to associate category with all posts by using sql query?

Answer (score -1):

You can run WordPress query to associate category to all posts.
Here is the code. What this code will do is check if a post is already in category id 67, if it's not then it will assign category id to it.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $category_id = 67;
        if ( !(in_category( $category_id )) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), array( $category_id ), 'category', false );
        }
    endforeach;
?>
```

Paste this code in header or footer and load your website in browser. Check category id's in admin section if all has been changed. If not then load website in browser again.

Don't forget to remove this code once done.

Comment: I posted it in footer but it doesn't work. Can you give me sql query code, please ?

Comment: I just tested this myself. it's working. You need to make sure that category already exists and you will need to replace your category id in above code.